# Having trouble with sleep.time, is there an alternative

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I'm writing a program to control GPIO's on my raspberry pi. I would like my program to ask me how long I would like to keep a GPIO on before it turns off.

Is it possible to have it stay on for 1 hour and then turn off. The problem I'm having is that when its on for an hour I cant issue any other commands to turn on other GPIO's because `sleep.time` is still being processed. I'd like to set multiple GPIO's for different times at the same time.

Comment: (depending on exactly what you're trying to do), you can create a dictionary with the keys being the different things you'd like to have different times on and the value being their amount of time you want them to sleep. You can then create a function that can add/remove some of the time just by accessing it in the dictionary

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your current script only have one thread running, the sleep() will put the current running thread into sleep mode which blocks further commands.

[time.sleep(secs) Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep)

> **time.sleep(secs)**
>
> Suspend execution of the current thread for the given number of seconds.

You will need one more thread on the background which keeps the timer for you. In the mean time, the thread on the foreground can still takes other commands.

I recommend you read this page
[threading – Manage concurrent threads](https://pymotw.com/2/threading/)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve the problem. Conceptually, instead of sleeping 30 seconds and then doing something, you can sleep one second, do a bunch of stuff, check the time, lather, rinse, repeat. And by "sleep one second" it could just as easily be a tenth of a second or five seconds or whatever seems reasonable to me.

Another solution is to create a second thread (or process) for this sleep command so that your main thread (or process) runs unabated.

The choice depends on what all you need to do, how accurate you need the delay to be, what other things are running on the system, and so on.

Comment: Thanks So much for the quick response!